# Video player which makes displayed subtitles selectable as text

Tags: windows, video, media-player, closed-captions

I'm looking for a video player that makes displayed subtitles select-able.

If you don't understand what I mean, this is an illustrative example of exactly what I need: Let's consider that I'm playing a video with subtitles. I want to be able to select a word or sentence from the appearing subtitles statement to copy it (add to clipboard).

*Operating Sytem:* Microsoft Windows 8.1

Something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[PotPlayer](https://potplayer.daum.net/) can do that.

Preferences (F5) - Subtitles - Word searching. It also can open browser page with a dictionary definition.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I made the media player [LLG-MP](https://github.com/engMaher/LLG-MP) for exactly the same purpose , hope it helps:

> it's main purpose is to gamify the language learning process through appending clickable subtitles/lyrics to different types of local/remote media with an onclick instant translation during the media stream flow